# Dplyr rolling balance

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to compute a balance column.

So, to show an example, I want to go from this:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A"),
                  start = c(5, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                  receipt = c(1, 5, 6, 4, 6),
                  out = c(4, 5, 3, 2, 5))

> df
  group start receipt out
1     A     5       1   4
2     A     0       5   5
3     A     0       6   3
4     A     0       4   2
5     A     0       6   5
```

to creating a new balance column like the following

```
> dfb
  group start receipt out balance
1     A     5       1   4       2
2     A     0       5   5       2
3     A     0       6   3       5
4     A     0       4   2       7
5     A     0       6   5       8
```

I tried the following attempt but it isn't working

```
dfc <- df %>%
       group_by(group) %>%
       mutate(balance = if_else(row_number() == 1, start + receipt - out, (lag(balance) + receipt) - out)) %>%
       ungroup()
```

Would really appreciate some help with this. Thanks!

Comment: why the `out` is different in `dfb` and `df`?

Comment: just fixed that now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `cumsum` from `dplyr`. Note: I had to change your initial `df` table to match the one in your required result because you have different data in "out".

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A"),
                  start = c(5, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                  receipt = c(1, 5, 6, 4, 6),
                  out = c(4, 5, 3, 2, 5))
dfc <- df %>%
       group_by(group) %>%
       mutate(balance=cumsum(start+receipt-out))

Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
Groups: group [1]

   group start receipt   out balance
  <fctr> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1      A     5       1     4       2
2      A     0       5     5       2
3      A     0       6     3       5
4      A     0       4     2       7
5      A     0       6     5       8
```

Comment: alternatively, `balance = start[1] + cumsum(receipt - out)`.